# integrate net module of node-js with adonis

Tags: node.js, sockets, adonis.js, tcpsocket

I need to work with sockets in `adonis-js`, I don’t want to use http based sockets providers, `webSockets` or `socket.io`., instead I want to use pure tcp communication with nodejs [net](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html) module. How can I integrate this with adonis js. I will expose this to mobile clients